# Is the set of all straight lines in the plane whose slope and y-intercept are integers countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is the set of all straight lines in the plane whose slope and y-intercept are integers countable?

I have meet 2 problem when answering this question.

1. I suspect this set is equipotent to the set of all straight lines in the plane whose slope and y-intercept are **positive integers**, but I don't know how to show.
2. I suspect the set of all straight lines in the plane whose slope and y-intercept are **positive integers** is equipotent to the set of all positive rational number, because we can simply treat the slope as the denominator, and the y-intercept as numerator, we'll then get a set of positive rational number. But how to show that the set of potive ratinoal number is countable?

Do anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Whether it is positive integers or integers makes no difference, since there is a straightforward bijection between positive integers and integers.  Send $1$ to $0$, and $2,4,6,8,\dots$ to $1,2,3,4,\dots$ and $3,5,7,\dots$ to $-1,-2,-3,\dots$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas: But seems it's not integers to positive integers, but integers*integers to positive integers*positive integers, do you get what I mean?

Comment: That's a separate problem. Use the Cantor pairing function. Or more simply send $(x,y)$ to $2^{x-1}(2y-1)$. I really don't want to write an answer, the problem has been solved repeatedly on MSE.

Comment: If f is a bijective map from N to P, then even $(m, n) \mapsto (f(m), f(n))$ should be bijective from NxN to PxP.

Comment: Define the function $f$ from ordered pairs of positive integers to positive integers, using $f(x,y)$ as in my comment above. Then $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: @ André Nicolas: Where was these kind problem asked before?

Comment: On this site. And I have written an answer at least once. So have others. I am lousy at searching, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any line with integer slope and y-intercept corresponds to a pair of integers. Thus, there is an invertible map from the set of all these lines and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Cartesian product of two countable sets are also countable. Hence this set of lines is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the a line in the plane is completely determined by its slope and a point. If you insist on having both integers then there are no more than $\Bbb{Z\times Z}$, which is equipotent with $\Bbb N$.